# checking and un-checking the checkbox in Jquery using the values from Sessionstorage

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am facing a issue where I am trying to set a number of checkbox depeneding on the value which I have in the sessionstorage. I have a main form, in which I have a tabular table with checkbox in each cell. Now on click of a icon, I am showing the same table in another tab of the browser, with more details where I need to have the same check box selection. Checkboxes are id'd same in both the windows. So i have used SessionStorage to share the selection value from one tab to another. Here is the code snippet.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  // this is to store all the existing checks into SessionStorage 
  jQuery('input[id^="chx_box_"]').each(function() {
      var chk_box = jQuery(this).attr("id");
      var IsChecked = (jQuery(this).attr('checked'))?true:false;
      sessionStorage.setItem(chk_box, IsChecked );
  });
```

});

In the new tab, I have this code.

```
  // this is update all the checkboxes with the current selection
  $('input[id^="chx_box_"]').each(function() {

      // Clearing the previous selections
      $(this).prop( 'checked', false  );

      var chk_box = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log( chk_box  );     // I am getting the checkbox id here
      var IsChecked = sessionStorage.getItem(chk_box);
      console.log( IsChecked  );   // I am getting true or false here

      // setting the current selection from the parent window

      // This is checking all the checkboxes in the new tab table....
      $(this).prop('checked', IsChecked  ); 


      // tried these below two as per some of the solutions from 
      // various questions in Stack Over flow. But no 
      // $(this).attr('checked', IsChecked  );
      // $(this)[0].checked =  IsChecked;

  });
```

I am using **jquery-1.11.3.min.js**.
I have two questions.
1. How to update the checkbox values if the user checks one checkbox in the one window and moves to the other window and verifies his selection

2. why is the above code checking all the check boxes,even when I am sending true or false parameter.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

i suppose it's because you get back the Strings "true" or "false" back from

```
var IsChecked = sessionStorage.getItem(chk_box);
```

In JavaScript each non empty String is truthy. This also true for the String "false".

You could try

```
var IsChecked = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(chk_box));
```

Answer (score 1):

To your question 1, you can use the [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) event. This event is fired only on other tabs / windows in the same domain when you store a value in localStorage.

For this you have to use localStorage, you cannot use sessionStorage, as sessionStorage is local to only one tab. The data will not be passed from one tab to another.

So when the user clicks on a checkbox, you need to update the value in localStorage, and the storage event will be fired.

```
$( window ).on( 'storage', function( ) {
    // your code here to handle the values.
} );
```

Unfortunately, even if the localStorage and sessionStorage work in IE, this event is not working as expected in IE ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage), see under "known issues")

To your question 2, it is because localStorage only stores strings. You have to convert it to a boolean value first.